# Wired result of my displaying procedure in Linux Assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I've got problem with my displaying procedure in Linux assm. Always when I try to use it, it display some wired characters in my terminal. I don't exactly know how to explain it, so I will show you on screen.
This is my code:

```
movl $10, %ebx
movl $8, %ecx
movl $123456789, %eax

zamiana:                                
    movl $0, %edx
    div %ebx
    add $'0', %dl                   
    mov %dl, wyswietl(%ecx) 
    dec %ecx        
    cmpl $0, %eax       
jnz zamiana

movl $wyswietl_len, %edx 
movl $wyswietl, %ecx 
movl $EXIT_SUCC, %ebx 
movl $SYSWRITE, %eax 
int $SYSCALL

movl $SYSEXIT, %eax
movl $EXIT_SUCC, %ebx
int $SYSCALL
```

Screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Grctk.png

Sorry, for Polish names. As you can see, in first line is proper result and then some garbage characters. What is wrong with this code?

Thank you in advance for the all information.

Comment: Use `strace`  and `gdb`

Comment: When I'm using gdb, everything looks fine.

Comment: What is `wyswietl_len`?

Comment: Length of my variable "wyswietl". wyswietl_len is declared as .long

Comment: And what value does it hold?

Comment: wyswietl_len: .long .-wyswietl

Comment: Um, shouldn't that be `movl wyswietl_len, %edx` (without a `$`) ? `edx` should contain the number of bytes to write, not a pointer to the number of bytes to write.

Comment: Ohhh, you're absolutely right! Thank you so much, it's so simple that I forget about it :)